# Reusing an old component in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm new to VHDL and following the labs provided by xilinx but I am lost on a certain part. In one of the labs I made a 2 bit wide 2to1 mux. In my current lab I'm supposed to use two of the old muxes to build a 3to1 mux. It doesn't explain at all how to do this so I'm taking a stab in the dark on this one. I'm getting the following error codes.

> [HDL 9-806] Syntax error near "end". ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_5_dataflow/lab1_5_dataflow.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_3_to_1_dat>aflow.vhd":48]
>
> [HDL 9-806] Syntax error near ";". ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_5_dataflow/lab1_5_dataflow.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_3_to_1_dat>aflow.vhd":52]
>
> [HDL 9-806] Syntax error near "=>". ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_5_dataflow/lab1_5_dataflow.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_3_to_1_dat>aflow.vhd":55]
>
> [HDL 9-806] Syntax error near ";". ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_5_dataflow/lab1_5_dataflow.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_3_to_1_dat>aflow.vhd":59]
>
> [HDL 9-806] Syntax error near "=>". ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_5_dataflow/lab1_5_dataflow.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_3_to_1_dat>aflow.vhd":62]

Here is my code for the main source file.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mux_2bit_3_to_1_dataflow is
Port ( u : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       v : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       w : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       s : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       o : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));
end mux_2bit_3_to_1_dataflow;

architecture Behavioral of mux_2bit_3_to_1_dataflow is
component mux_2bit_2_to_1 port
(
    x, y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
    s : in STD_LOGIC;
    m : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR
) end component;
signal a : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
begin
mux1 : mux_2bit_2_to_1 port map (
    x => u;                                            LINE 52
    y => v;
    s => s(1);
    m => a                                             LINE 55
);

mux2 : mux_2bit_2_to_1 port map (
     x => a;                                           LINE 59
     y => w;
     s => s(0);
     m => o;                                           LINE 62
);
    

end Behavioral;
```

And here is the source file to the 2 to 1 mux I added to the project.

```
entity mux_2bit_2_to_1 is
Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       s : in STD_LOGIC;
       m : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));
end mux_2bit_2_to_1;

architecture Behavioral of mux_2bit_2_to_1 is

begin
m(0) <= (x(0) and not s) or (y(0) and s);
m(1) <= (x(1) and not s) or (y(1) and s);


end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First, you miss a semicolon before `end component;`:

```
component mux_2bit_2_to_1
port (
    x, y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
    s : in STD_LOGIC;
    m : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR
); -- <--- semicolon here
end component;
```

Second thing, you use colon when assigning ports in an instantiation:

```
mux1 : mux_2bit_2_to_1 port map (
    x => u,
    y => v,
    s => s(1),
    m => a
);
```

Finally, on your second instantiation you use a semicolon on the last port (`m`). First, no semicolon on port instantiation and second, no colon on the last assignation, before the closing parentheses.